# React ajax fetch response undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am using the fetch AJAX example from the docs and am fetching this:

```
 https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json
```

Here is the componentDidMount part:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch("https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: result.items
      });
    },
```

I get "uncaught type error in promise, cannot read property map of undefined"

Why is this happening? This is my first attempt to use the fetch API. I have tried to log the response object, but that returns undefined.

The link to the pen is here:

```
 https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/yQLbxV
```

Comment: The *reason* the site wouldn't let you post that codepen link without obscuring it is that your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please put all necessary code **in** your question, ideally using Stack Snippets; [here's how to do a React one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Side note (because it's probably not *the* problem, it's just *a* problem): You're not checking for `fetch` failure. You're not the only one, they clearly got the API wrong, this is so common I [wrote it up in a post on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result is the array of items hence result.items does not exist:

```
componentDidMount() {
 fetch("https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json")
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(result => {
     console.log(result)
     this.setState({
       isLoaded: true,
       items: result
     });
   })
 .catch(error => {
   this.setState({
     isLoaded: true,
     error
   });
 })
}
```

https://codepen.io/mThorning/pen/ZmEyao?editors=0010

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error in render method.

Remove items from `result.item`, because data is in 'result'.

Like below

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch("https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: result // remove items, because data is in 'result'
      });
    },
```